# Python inputs involving [mm:ss]

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

So I have to make a program for pacing running

my teacher wants the inputs to look like this

```
1 Enter pace [mm:ss]: 8:15
2 Enter distance [miles]: 26.2
```

So I went and did this for the inputs

```
1 pace=input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: ")
2 dist=input("Enter distance [miles]: ")
```

But I don't know how to get around the ":" because there is no way(I know of yet) to make it ignore the ":" and only use the integers.

Comment: `mm,ss = map(int, pace.split(':'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
pace=input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: ")
dist=input("Enter distance [miles]: ")    
unixTime = time.mktime(time.strptime(pace, '%M:%S'))
```

Easier to work with seconds than it is wil string-formatted time, and `strptime` in junction with `mktime` will convert your string into seconds.

For whatever reason I'm confusing you even further but the above idea should work, just can't figure it out myself but instead of deleting the entire answer i'll give a working solution that's a bit of an ugly hack:

```
import time
pace=input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: ")
dist=input("Enter distance [miles]: ")    
unixTime = time.time() - time.mktime(time.strptime(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:')+pace, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

That will give you how many seconds the users pace in seconds.

1. `time.time()` will give you the current time in seconds
2. `time.mktime()` will convert a `struct_time` object into seconds since the epoch
3. `time.strptime()` converts '2014-02-20' into a seconds since the epoch representation
4. `time.strftime()` is simply used to generate missing data in the input string in order to properly calculate seconds "running" against `time()`

More on [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 0):

To get the pace interval in seconds:

```
 pace=input("Enter pace [mm:ss]: ")
 pace_in_seconds = (int(pace.split(':')[0]) * 60) + int(pace.split(':')[1])
```